# Method to do compare and change single characters in a string

Tags: java, string, compare

I need to do a method to check two string for example bod and bot or crab and rab. The method needs to print out what the user must do in order to make them equal. For example in bod and bot it will print "replace,2,d in the string". I used this code which seems to work.

```
    if(a.length()==b.length()){
        int i;
        for(i=0; i<=a.length(); i++){
            if(a.charAt(i)!=b.charAt(i)){
                return "replace,"+ i + "," + b.charAt(i);
                }
            }
        }
```

But I am having troubles if the two string are not equal in size. I use this but it doesn't work because one of the strings is bigger.

```
    int aS = a.length();
    int bS = b.length();
    if(bS - aS == 1){
        int i;
        for(i=0; i<=b.length(); i++){
            if(b.charAt(i)!=a.charAt(i)){
                return "remove," + i;
            }
        }
    }
```

Can you guys give me a suggestion what method I can use to check which is the extra letter or vice versa a letter I can add and then return a string saying either to remove a character or add an extra one. Thank you

Comment: do the strings only differ by one character?

Comment: Yes it all the string will differ by one character

Comment: It seems to me that the remove method should work except you risk going beyond the bound of the shorter string, e.g., car and cart. So you should only compare up to the length of the shorter string (exclusive), and if they are equal that far, remove the last char of the longer string. Hope it helps.

Comment: Yes but what happens when the difference is in the middle or at the start

Comment: @Bakslat posted an answer :D

Comment: Bakslat, the code you posted in the question, what does it do if the difference is in the start or in the middle? Does it already behave correctly, and if not, in what way not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe something like this?

```
public ArrayList<String> createConversionList(String primary, String secondary){
  //Determine which string is shorter.
  String shorter;
  String longer;
  boolean primaryIsShorter = false;
  if (primary.length() >= secondary.length()){
    longer = primary;
    shorter = secondary;
  } else{
    longer = secondary;
    shorter = primary;
    primaryIsShorter = true;
  }

  //Fills an array with all the character positions that differ between the
  //two strings, using the shorter string as the base.
  int[] posOfCharsToChange = new int[shorter.length()];
  for(int i = 0; i < shorter.length(); i++){
    if(shorter.charAt(i) != longer.charAt(i)){
      posOfCharsToChange[i] = i;
    } else{
      posOfCharsToChange[i] = -1;
    }
  }

  //Adds to an ArrayList all of the "Replace" strings.
  ArrayList<String> conversionList = new ArrayList();
  for(int pos: posOfCharsToChange){
    if(pos != -1){
      String s = "Replace " + secondary.charAt(pos) + " with " + primary.charAt(pos) + ". \n";
      conversionList.add(s);
    }
  }

  //Depending on which string was bigger, either adds "Add" or "Remove"
  //strings to the ArrayList. If the strings were the same size, does
  //nothing.
  if(primary.length() != secondary.length()){
    if(primaryIsShorter){
      for(int i = primary.length(); i < secondary.length(); i++){
        String s = "Remove " + secondary.charAt(i) + ". \n";
        conversionList.add(s);
      }
    }
    else{
      for(int i = secondary.length(); i < primary.length(); i++){
        String s = "Add " + primary.charAt(i) + ". \n";
        conversionList.add(s);
      }
    }
  }

  return conversionList;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My Approach works as follows

1)  We take the smaller string and put all its contents in an arraylist

2)  We take the bigger string and put its contents in the arraylist only if its not present in the arraylist

3) The last character in the arraylist must be removed from the bigger string to make them equal

Ex 1: 
a = rab
b = crab

1) arraylist = rab  -> contents of a added

2) arraylist = rab**c**  -> only unique content of b is added

Ex 2:
a = crab 
b = rab

1) arraylist = rab

2) arraylist = rabc

similarly if the positions are in the middle or not at start ,

ex : a = racb
     b = rab

1) arraylist = rab

2) arraylist = rab**c**

```
public class Replace {

public static void main(String args[]) {
    int p = 0, j = 0;
    String a = "rab";
    String b = "crab";

    if (b.length() < a.length()) {

        ArrayList al = new ArrayList();

        for (j = 0; j < b.length(); j++) {
            if (!al.contains(b.charAt(j))) {
                al.add(b.charAt(j));
            }

        }

        for (j = 0; j < a.length(); j++) {
            if (!al.contains(a.charAt(j))) {
                al.add(a.charAt(j));
            }

        }

        System.out.println("Remove " + al.get(al.size() - 1)
                + " from String a");
    } else {

        ArrayList al = new ArrayList();

        for (j = 0; j < a.length(); j++) {
            if (!al.contains(a.charAt(j))) {
                al.add(a.charAt(j));
            }

        }

        for (j = 0; j < b.length(); j++) {
            if (!al.contains(b.charAt(j))) {
                al.add(b.charAt(j));
            }

        }

        System.out.println("Remove " + al.get(al.size() - 1)
                + " from String b");

    }

  }

}
```

Note - The program only works under your given contraints that strings only differ in one character and the ordering of both the strings is not different if we remove or add that charcter.